# First Accordion always open in the mobile

Tags: javascript, tabs, responsive, accordion

I want all accordions closed in mobile view. Currently the first one is always open in the mobile view. In desktop the accordions are in tabs. The content of the first tab should always remain displayed in the mobile view. This is also how it is currently displayed. But I want all accordions to be closed in the mobile version.  Can someone please help me to rewrite the script that only in the mobile version all accordions are closed?

Thanks a lot!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.0/dist/aos.css">

    <style>

        *, *::before, *::after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        code {
            font-family: Consolas,monaco,monospace;
            line-height: 1.75;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
            padding: 6px 8px 2px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            opacity: 0.65;
        }

        .tabs-tab-list {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .tabs-tab-list li {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .tabs-trigger {
            border-bottom: none;
            color: #505052;
            display: none;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0 5px 0 1px;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .tabs-trigger:hover {
            border-bottom: none;
            color: #888;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .tabs-trigger.is-selected, .tabs-trigger.is-selected:hover, .tabs-trigger.is-selected:focus {
            color: #505052;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #75b823;
            font-weight: bold;

        }

        .tabs-trigger:active {
            outline: none;
        }

        .tabs-panel {
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .tabs-panel:not(:first-of-type) {
            border-top: 2px solid #eee;
        }

        .tabs-panel:not(:last-child) {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        }

        .tabs-panel:not(:last-child) {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .tabs-panel .content {
        }

        .tabs-panel.is-hidden .content {
            display: none;
        }

        .tabs-panel:active, .tabs-panel:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        .is-initialized.tabs-allowed .tabs-panel {
            display: inherit;
        }

        .accordeon-trigger {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 15px 20px;
        }

        .accordeon-trigger-icon {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 40em) {
            .tabs-allowed .accordeon-trigger {
                display: none;
            }
            .tabs-allowed .tabs-trigger {
                display: block;
            }
            .tabs-allowed .tabs-panel {
                display: none;
            }
            .tabs-allowed .tabs-panel.is-hidden {
                display: none;
            }
            .tabs-allowed .tabs-panel {
                border-top: 2px solid #eee;
            }
            .tabs-allowed .tabs-tab-list {
                margin-bottom: -2px;
            }
        }

        .accordeon-trigger-icon {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            width: 22px;
            height: 22px;
        }

        .accordeon-trigger-icon svg {
            margin: 0;
        }

        [aria-expanded="true"] .vert {
            display: none;
        }

        .label--open, .label--close {
            display: block;
            border: 0;
            clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
            height: 1px;
            margin: -1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 1px;
        }

        .label--close {
            display: none;
        }

        .is-open .label--open {
            display: none;
        }

        .is-open .label--close {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>






<!-- Tabs -------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <section class="accordion-tabs js-tabs" data-tabs-allowed="true" data-breakpoint="400" data-start-collapsed="false">
            <ul role="tablist" class="tabs-tab-list page-width">


                <li onclick="myFunction()" role="presentation"><a id="tab1" href="#section1" role="tab" aria-controls="section1" class="tabs-trigger js-tabs-trigger">Section 1</a></li>
                <li onclick="myFunction()" role="presentation"><a id="tab2" href="#section2" role="tab" aria-controls="section2" class="tabs-trigger js-tabs-trigger">Section 2</a></li>
                <li onclick="myFunction()" role="presentation"><a id="tab3" href="#section3" role="tab" aria-controls="section3" class="tabs-trigger js-tabs-trigger">Section 3</a></li>
                <li onclick="myFunction()" role="presentation"><a id="tab4" href="#section4" role="tab" aria-controls="section4" class="tabs-trigger js-tabs-trigger">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <section id="section1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1" class="tabs-panel js-tabs-panel" tabindex="0">
                <div class="accordeon-trigger js-accordeon-trigger" aria-controls="section1" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">Section 1
                    <div class="accordeon-trigger-icon"><span class="label--open">Open</span><span class="label--close">Close</span> <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 20 20"> <rect class="vert" height="18" width="2" fill="currentColor" y="1" x="9"></rect> <rect height="2" width="18" fill="currentColor" y="9" x="1"></rect>
                    </svg></div></div>

                <div class="content" aria-hidden="false">
                    <h1>
                        content
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </section>



            <section id="section2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2" class="tabs-panel js-tabs-panel" tabindex="1">
                <div  class="accordeon-trigger js-accordeon-trigger" aria-controls="section2" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="1">Section 2
                    <div class="accordeon-trigger-icon"><span class="label--open">Open</span><span class="label--close">Close</span><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 20 20"> <rect class="vert" height="18" width="2" fill="currentColor" y="1" x="9"></rect> <rect height="2" width="18" fill="currentColor" y="9" x="1"></rect> </svg></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content" aria-hidden="true"><!--TAB 2 ------------------------------------------------->
                <h1>
                    Content
                </h1>

                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="section3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3" class="tabs-panel js-tabs-panel" tabindex="2">
                <div class="accordeon-trigger js-accordeon-trigger" aria-controls="section3" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="2">Section 3
                    <div class="accordeon-trigger-icon"><span class="label--open">Open</span><span class="label--close">Close</span><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 20 20"> <rect class="vert" height="18" width="2" fill="currentColor" y="1" x="9"></rect> <rect height="2" width="18" fill="currentColor" y="9" x="1"></rect> </svg></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content" aria-hidden="true"><!--TAB 3 ------------------------------------------------->
                    <h1>
                        <h1>content</h1>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="section4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab4" class="tabs-panel js-tabs-panel" tabindex="3">
                <div class="accordeon-trigger js-accordeon-trigger" aria-controls="section4" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="3">Section 4
                    <div class="accordeon-trigger-icon"><span class="label--open">Open</span><span class="label--close">Close</span><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 20 20"> <rect class="vert" height="18" width="2" fill="currentColor" y="1" x="9"></rect> <rect height="2" width="18" fill="currentColor" y="9" x="1"></rect> </svg></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content" aria-hidden="true"><!--TAB 4 ------------------------------------------------->
                  <div>
                      <h1>Content</h1>
                  </div>

                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>



</body>


<script>

    (function () {

        'use strict';

        function AccordionTabs (el, options) {


            if (!el) {
                return;
            }

            this.el = el;
            this.tabTriggers = this.el.getElementsByClassName('js-tabs-trigger');
            this.tabPanels = this.el.getElementsByClassName('js-tabs-panel');
            this.accordeonTriggers = this.el.getElementsByClassName('js-accordeon-trigger');

            this.options = this._extend({
                breakpoint: 640,
                tabsAllowed: true,
                selectedTab: 0,
                startCollapsed: true,
            }, options);

            if(el.getAttribute('data-tabs-allowed') == "true"){
                this.options.tabsAllowed = true;
            } else if (el.getAttribute('data-tabs-allowed') == "false") {
                this.options.tabsAllowed = false;
            }

            if(el.getAttribute('data-breakpoint')){
                this.options.breakpoint = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-breakpoint'));
            }

            if(el.getAttribute('data-selected-tab')){
                this.options.selectedTab = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-selected-tab'));
            }

            if(el.getAttribute('data-start-collapsed')){
                this.options.startCollapsed = el.getAttribute('data-start-collapsed');
            }

            if (this.tabTriggers.length === 0 || this.tabTriggers.length !== this.tabPanels.length) {
                return;
            }

            this._init();
        }

        AccordionTabs.prototype._init = function () {

            var _this = this;

            this.tabTriggersLength = this.tabTriggers.length;
            this.accordeonTriggersLength = this.accordeonTriggers.length;
            this.selectedTab = 0;
            this.prevSelectedTab = null;
            this.clickListener = this._clickEvent.bind(this);
            this.keydownListener = this._keydownEvent.bind(this);
            this.keys = {
                prev: 37,
                next: 39,
                space: 32,
                enter: 13
            };

            if(window.innerWidth >= this.options.breakpoint && this.options.tabsAllowed) {
                this.isAccordeon = false;
            } else {
                this.isAccordeon = true;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < this.tabTriggersLength; i++) {
                this.tabTriggers[i].index = i;
                this.tabTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', this.clickListener, false);
                this.tabTriggers[i].addEventListener('keydown', this.keydownListener, false);

                if (this.tabTriggers[i].classList.contains('is-selected')) {
                    this.selectedTab = i;
                }

                this._hide(i);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < this.accordeonTriggersLength; i++) {
                this.accordeonTriggers[i].index = i;
                this.accordeonTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', this.clickListener, false);
                this.accordeonTriggers[i].addEventListener('keydown', this.keydownListener, false);

                if (this.accordeonTriggers[i].classList.contains('is-selected')) {
                    this.selectedTab = i;
                }
            }

            if (!isNaN(this.options.selectedTab)) {
                this.selectedTab = this.options.selectedTab < this.tabTriggersLength ? this.options.selectedTab : this.tabTriggersLength - 1;
            }

            this.el.classList.add('is-initialized');
            if (this.options.tabsAllowed) {
                this.el.classList.add('tabs-allowed');
            }






            // If the accordion should not start collapsed, open the first element
            if(this.options.startCollapsed != "true"){
                this.selectTab(this.selectedTab, false);
            }

            var resizeTabs = this._debounce(function() {
                // This gets delayed for performance reasons
                if(window.innerWidth >= _this.options.breakpoint && _this.options.tabsAllowed) {
                    _this.isAccordeon = false;
                    if (_this.options.tabsAllowed) {
                        _this.el.classList.add('tabs-allowed');
                    }
                    _this.selectTab(_this.selectedTab);
                } else {
                    _this.isAccordeon = true;
                    _this.el.classList.remove('tabs-allowed');
                    _this.selectTab(_this.selectedTab);
                }

            }, 50);

            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeTabs);

        };

        AccordionTabs.prototype._clickEvent = function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var closestTrigger = this._getClosest(e.target, '.js-tabs-trigger');
            var closestTab = 0;

            if (closestTrigger == null) {
                closestTrigger = this._getClosest(e.target, '.js-accordeon-trigger');
                closestTab = this._getClosest(closestTrigger, '.js-tabs-panel');
                this.isAccordeon = true;
            } else {
                this.isAccordeon = false;
            }

            var targetIndex = e.target.index != null ? e.target.index : closestTab.index;

            if (targetIndex === this.selectedTab && !this.isAccordeon) {
                return;
            }

            this.selectTab(targetIndex, true);
        };

        AccordionTabs.prototype._keydownEvent = function (e) {

            var targetIndex;

            if (e.keyCode === this.keys.prev || e.keyCode === this.keys.next || e.keyCode === this.keys.space || e.keyCode === this.keys.enter) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                return;
            }

            if (e.keyCode === this.keys.prev && e.target.index > 0 && !this.isAccordeon) {
                targetIndex = e.target.index - 1;
            }
            else if (e.keyCode === this.keys.next && e.target.index < this.tabTriggersLength - 1 && !this.isAccordeon) {
                targetIndex = e.target.index + 1;
            }
            else if (e.keyCode === this.keys.space || e.keyCode === this.keys.enter) {
                targetIndex = e.target.index;
            }
            else {
                return;
            }

            this.selectTab(targetIndex, true);
        };

        AccordionTabs.prototype._show = function (index, userInvoked) {

            this.tabPanels[index].removeAttribute('tabindex');

            this.tabTriggers[index].removeAttribute('tabindex');
            this.tabTriggers[index].classList.add('is-selected');
            this.tabTriggers[index].setAttribute('aria-selected', true);

            this.accordeonTriggers[index].setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);

            var panelContent = this.tabPanels[index].getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
            panelContent.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
            panelContent.classList.remove('is-hidden');
            panelContent.classList.add('is-hidden');

            this.tabPanels[index].classList.remove('is-hidden');
            this.tabPanels[index].classList.add('is-open');

            if (userInvoked) {
                this.tabTriggers[index].focus();
            }
        };

        AccordionTabs.prototype._hide = function (index) {

            this.tabTriggers[index].classList.remove('is-selected');
            this.tabTriggers[index].setAttribute('aria-selected', false);
            this.tabTriggers[index].setAttribute('tabindex', -1);

            this.accordeonTriggers[index].setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);

            var panelContent = this.tabPanels[index].getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
            panelContent.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
            panelContent.classList.remove('is-open');
            panelContent.classList.add('is-hidden');

            this.tabPanels[index].classList.remove('is-open');
            this.tabPanels[index].classList.add('is-hidden');
            this.tabPanels[index].setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
        };

        AccordionTabs.prototype.selectTab = function (index, userInvoked) {

            if (index === null) {
                if(this.isAccordeon) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    index = 0;
                }
            }

            if(!this.tabPanels[index].classList.contains('is-hidden') && userInvoked) {

                if (index === this.selectedTab) {
                    this.selectedTab = null;
                } else {
                    this.selectedTab = null;
                    this.prevSelectedTab = index;
                }

                this._hide(index);

                return;
            }

            if (this.isAccordeon) {

                this.prevSelectedTab = this.selectedTab;
                this.selectedTab = index;

            } else {
                if (this.prevSelectedTab === null || !this.isAccordeon) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.tabTriggersLength; i++) {
                        if (i !== index) {
                            this._hide(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this._hide(this.selectedTab);
                }

                this.prevSelectedTab = this.selectedTab;
                this.selectedTab = index;
            }

            this._show(this.selectedTab, userInvoked);

        };

        AccordionTabs.prototype.destroy = function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < this.tabTriggersLength; i++) {
                this.tabTriggers[i].classList.remove('is-selected');
                this.tabTriggers[i].removeAttribute('aria-selected');
                this.tabTriggers[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');

                this.tabPanels[i].classList.remove('is-hidden');
                this.tabPanels[i].removeAttribute('aria-hidden');
                this.tabPanels[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');

                this.tabTriggers[i].removeEventListener('click', this.clickListener, false);
                this.tabTriggers[i].removeEventListener('keydown', this.keydownListener, false);

                delete this.tabTriggers[i].index;
            }

            this.el.classList.remove('is-initialized');
        };

        /**
         * Get the closest matching element up the DOM tree.
         * @private
         * @param  {Element} elem     Starting element
         * @param  {String}  selector Selector to match against
         * @return {Boolean|Element}  Returns null if not match found
         */
        AccordionTabs.prototype._getClosest = function ( elem, selector ) {

            // Element.matches() polyfill
            if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
                Element.prototype.matches =
                    Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
                    Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
                    Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
                    Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
                    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                    function(s) {
                        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                            i = matches.length;
                        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
                        return i > -1;
                    };
            }

            // Get closest match
            for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) {
                if ( elem.matches( selector ) ) return elem;
            }

            return null;

        };

        // Pass in the objects to merge as arguments.
        // For a deep extend, set the first argument to `true`.
        AccordionTabs.prototype._extend = function () {

            // Variables
            var extended = {};
            var deep = false;
            var i = 0;
            var length = arguments.length;

            // Check if a deep merge
            if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Boolean]' ) {
                deep = arguments[0];
                i++;
            }

            // Merge the object into the extended object
            var merge = function (obj) {
                for ( var prop in obj ) {
                    if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
                        // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
                        if ( deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ) {
                            extended[prop] = extend( true, extended[prop], obj[prop] );
                        } else {
                            extended[prop] = obj[prop];
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                var obj = arguments[i];
                merge(obj);
            }

            return extended;

        };

        // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
        // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
        // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
        // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
        AccordionTabs.prototype._debounce = function (func, wait, immediate) {
            var timeout;
            return function() {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                var later = function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) { func.apply(context, args); };
                };
                var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                if (callNow) { func.apply(context, args) };
            };
        };

        var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

        function $(expr, con) {
            return typeof expr === "string" ? (con || document).querySelector(expr) : expr || null;
        }

        function $$(expr, con) {
            return slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
        }

        // Initialization

        function init() {
            $$(".js-tabs").forEach(function (input) {
                new AccordionTabs(input);
            });
        }

        // Are we in a browser? Check for Document constructor
        if (typeof Document !== "undefined") {
            // DOM already loaded?
            if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
                init();
            }
            else {
                // Wait for it
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
            }
        }

        // Export on self when in a browser
        if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
            self.AccordionTabs = AccordionTabs;
        }

        // Expose as a CJS module
        if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
            module.exports = AccordionTabs;
        }

        return AccordionTabs;

    })();
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.0/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
    AOS.init({
        duration: 1200,
    })
</script>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




</html>
```